# How to use a button to submit data, load a new page and load json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I am trying to use an api to build an app that takes JSON data from an api, I need to have a button on my index page, then when I input a car registration the information loads in another page.

I currently have the information loading with user input, with  tags and a submit button, but I do not know how to have the input and button on a seperate page then load the json data. here's what I have so far.

```
<form id="vehicle-smart-sample-form">
        <label for="reg">Enter your reg</label>
        <input type="text" id="reg"/>
    <a href="stats.html"><button type="submit">Search</button></a>
    </form>

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#vehicle-smart-sample-form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var reg = $("#reg").val();
            $.ajax({
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": "https://www.getvehiclesmart.com/rest/vehicleData?reg=" + reg + "&isRefreshing=false&appid="+myAppId,
                "method": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/text",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
                }
            })
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand exactly, If you want open new blank page and show Json data in that you can use this on ajax options

```
success: function(data){
var myWindow = window.open("_blank");
myWindow.document.write("<p>"+data.property+"</p>");//for example
}
```

and you can also open "stats.html" and load Json data in it.

```
success: function(data){
var myWindow = window.open("stats.html", "_blank");
myWindow.document.getElementById("car_info").innerText = data.carinfo;//for example
}
```